# Missing model when solving Exists-Expression

Tags: z3

I was setting up an example using the Java-API (along the lines of the provided Z3 Java examples):

```
Context ctx = new Context();

        int size = 1;
        IntExpr[] xs = new IntExpr[size];
        Symbol[] names = new Symbol[size];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            names[j] = ctx.mkSymbol("x_" + Integer.toString(j));
            xs[j] = (IntExpr) ctx.mkConst(names[j], ctx.getIntSort());
        }

        BoolExpr body_const = ctx.mkEq(xs[0], ctx.mkInt(3));
        BoolExpr exists = ctx.mkExists(xs, body_const, 1, null, null,
                null, null);

        Solver s = ctx.mkSolver();
        s.add(exists);
        if (s.check() != Status.SATISFIABLE)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        Model model = s.getModel();

        System.out.println("---> " + model);
```

I wonder why the model is empty! Shouldn't it simply state that xs[0] is 3?

Answer (score 1):

The entire Java program is just clutter in this context. Essentially, you're asking the solver the following SMTLib question:

```
(assert (exists ((x_0 Int)) (= x_0 3)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When run, the above prints:

```
sat
(
)
```

That is, it is indeed satisfiable, but there's no model to display. Because SMT solvers do *not* display values of existentially quantified variables like this. The model only contains values that are declared at the top-level. So, instead, you need to ask something like:

```
(declare-const x_0 Int)
(assert (= x_0 3))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

to which you'll get the model:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun x_0 () Int
    3)
)
```

Hope that helps out. So, if the Java program you gave is indeed what you intended, then the output is correct; by design you do not get the values of "existentially" quantified variables from an SMT solver. If you want to get them, make them top-level variables instead.